# How to use invert "-v" in grep when I do not have a file but a long string that is just one line?

Tags: linux, grep

Supposed I have

`echo "The first part. The second part. The third part."`

and want to remove `The first part` and `The third part` to get:

`The second part.`

I tried:

`echo "The first part. The second part. The third part." | grep -v -e "The first part." -e "The third part."`

but the inverting flag appears to work only for files with multiple lines. How can I do it for a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` instead:

```
echo "The first part. The second part. The third part." \
| sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*The first part\.[[:space:]]*//g' \
      -e 's/[[:space:]]*The third part\.[[:space:]]*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

grep is a tool which works line-based and is more as a *select-lines-which-satesfy-condition* tool, The task you want to implement is more *remove-substrings-from-file*. This is in the area of substitutions and not in the area of selection: The best tool for this task is to use `sed`

```
sed 's/string_to_get_rid_of//g' file
```

Of course it is possible that your file is structured in records and you want to remove all records which contain a particular word, then there is another option. Assume that your file is split into various records which are delimited by a unique character (eg. <full-stop>-character  (`.`)). The it is better to use `awk` for this. Awk allows you to redefine it's record separator from a new-line (default) to anything you want by defining `RS` and `ORS` (the latter for the output):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="."}/string_that_should_not_appear/{next}1' file
```

Assume you have a file with the content:

```
foo.bar.baz.qux
quux.quuz.corge
```

If we want to remove all the records which do not contain `qux`, we do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="."}/qux/{next}1' file
```

which returns

```
foo.bar.baz.quuz.corge.
```

Notice that the record containing "cux" contained a newline and that an extra ORS is added at the end. Also you might get

```
foo.bar.baz.quuz.corge
.
```

Which is due to the POSIX standard that files should end with a newline

In case of the OP, it would read:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="."}/The first part/{next}/The third part/{next}1' file
```